# appengine send data as a file download

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm new to python and appengine.So I have this simple problem.I want to send the server data and have the server send it back as a file download.I can get a file to download if I do it before a page loads. But after that I can't get the download.Here is what I have right now:

```
class UploadHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):

  def get(self):
    try:    
        xml=parseString(self.request.body)
        result=sanitize(xml)
        if result == None:
          text=xml.toxml('UTF-8')
          name="file.xml"   
          self.response.out.write(text)
          self.response.headers.add_header('Method','get')
          self.response.headers.add_header('Content-Type','text/xml')
          self.response.headers.add_header('name',name)
          self.response.headers.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment')
          self.response.headers.add_header('filename',name)
          self.response.headers.add_header('Content',text)
   except:
        print self.request.body
```

And here is the javascript to call it:

```
        var text=getMarkup();
        new Ajax.Request("http://localhost:8080/file",{
        method:'get',
        contentType:"text",
        postBody:text,
        onSuccess:function(){
            console.log(transport.responseText);            
        },          
        onFailure: function(){ 
            console.log('Could not load file...'); 
        },
        onException: function(req,exception) {
            console.log(exception);
            return true;
            }, 
        });
```

I've tried changing both pieces many different ways.I can get a response, but I can't get it to go to the downloads.If I use the same code for the main page it works though.What am I missing?

Finally got it....
I use the example on this page [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview)
only I sent the url back as the response and used window.open in the "onsuccess" handler to open it.

The problem with the blobstore is that the files are saved on the server and other people can view them, so my best solution is just to use a global variable to save the data from the post and then pass it to get and call get from javascript with window.open().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will help

```
import mimetypes
...... 

(content_type, _) = mimetypes.guess_type(name)
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = content_type
self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + name
self.response.out.write(text)
```

By the way. You can also use the blobstore to save your file and download the blob file.

Comment: I tried this and I still can't get it to download as a file.I even tried the blobstore.The contents com back right and it says "content-disposition:attachment" but it only comes back as data. maybe it's the javascript?

Comment: I do not understand your comment? Where you able to download the XML youself using the link. If that is the case, the server software works fine and the problem is in the javascript. By the way, when you download a blob this : self.send_blob(blob_info, save_as=True) is important. I mean the : "save_as:True"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Content-Type: application/force-download?
It will indicate that you are sending a file from server and that user would like to download (not view) it.

```
self.response.headers.add_header('Content-Type','application/force-download')
```